# Prove that $C_n+C_n$ is a critical graph and its chromatic number is 6.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

**Definitions**

The **union** $G=G_1+G_2$ of $G_1$ and $G_2$ has vertex set $V(G)=V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ and edge set $E(G)=E(G_1)\cup E(G_2)$. The union $G+G$ of two disjoint copies of $G$ is denoted by $2G$.

The **join** $G=G_1 \vee G_2$ of $G_1$ and $G_2$ has vertex set $V(G)=V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ and edge set $E(G)=E(G_1)\cup E(G_2)\cup \{uv:u\in V(G_1), v\in V(G_2)\}$.

For this exercise, I don't think it's not about the **union** but about the **join**, since the chromatic number of $C_n+C_n$ is $2$ if $n$ is even or $3$ if $n$ is odd.

If it is the **join** we must show that:

a) $G \vee H$ is a critical graph if and only if both $G$ and $H$ are a critical graph.

b) $\chi (G\vee H)=\chi (G)+\chi (H)$

c) $C_n$ is a critical graph if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Must have been some omissions here. It _has_ to be the join, and furthermore $n$ must be odd for $C_n$ to be critical.

Comment: I also think that something is missing, but there is no further information.

Comment: It is the join. Normally when one says $G_1 + G_2$, it refers to the join. It's a common notation.